# I don't have API Gateway, ALB or Cloudfront what are my solution for the WAF in my AWS environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I'm new to AWS and I was wondering if there are other WAF solutions if I don't have any of the services above for a web application.
On the document I only see deployment with those services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAF only provide integration with other AWS service like you mentioned, if you are looking for self-managed WAF tool you can try [nginx-modsecurity-waf](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-waf/admin-guide/nginx-plus-modsecurity-waf-installation-logging/#installing-the-nginx-modsecurity-waf) which you can run on the top of your application.

> NGINX Plus Release 12 and later support the **NGINX ModSecurity WAF**. The NGINX ModSecurity WAF protects web applications against SQL Injection (SQLi), Remote Code Execution (RCE), Local File Include (LFI), cross‑site scripting (XSS), and many other attacks.

You can also explore another paid service by Nginx App project.
[image]

> NGINX App Protect is a modern app‑security solution that works seamlessly in DevOps environments as you deliver apps from code to customer. Built on F5’s market‑leading WAF, our software runs natively on NGINX Plus and integrates security controls into your apps.

[nginx-app-protect](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-app-protect/)